# Should I re-standardize data when updating LSTM model with new data?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm

I'm fitting an LSTM for timeseries data and I'm hoping to train it "dynamically"—e.g. train it initially and then re-train/update with the next timestep when I get that data. Right now I'm fitting the standardizer (sklearn's `StandardScaler`) on only the initial training set and then transforming future samples with that standardizer. My question is whether I should instead fit the standardizer *each* timestep before re-training. My intuitive thoughts are:

- Maybe I should do this because otherwise the data could be poorly scaled if future timesteps have ranges beyond the range seen in the original training set (which is true of my data)
- Maybe I shouldn't do this because the weights are trained for the data as it was standardized originally, so this might mess things up.

Any advice is appreciated and if there is a good source on this sort of thing, please let me know!

Thanks